# How can we fit the data to Multi linear regression with a skew exponential distribution error?

Tags: multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, skewness, exponential-distribution

If the error term follows an exponential distribution, what would happen to our least square estimators? Are they still useful?

Can you use exponential distribution and MLE to estimate the parameters?
How would you compare the result from MLE with that from Least Square?

**UPDATE**

When we estimate parameters using MLE, we are fitting b1 and b2 so that the error terms follow normal distribution. Now, we can easily do the same thing to fit an exponential distribution using MLE. My question is would the result make any sense?

Similar, when we are using least-square, we are not making any assumption with the distribution of the error term; we only assume its first and second moment. It seems that least square does not care that much about the underlying distribution and the parameter would still make sense. Is this statement correct? Is it going to break anything?

How would you compare the result of MLE with that from Least Square?

Please correct me if I am understanding anything wrong.

Comment: When you say "skew exponential distribution" do you mean Azzalini's (1986) skew exponential power distribution (as your title might suggest), or the ordinary exponential (as your first sentence implies)? If you mean ordinary exponential errors, do you mean to have additive (conditional distribution is shifted-exponential presumably with constant scale, which you might use quantile regression for) or multiplicative errors (conditionally one parameter exponential with scale given by the conditional mean, as you'd have with a generalized linear model)?

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure, you are not using censored data, are you? They sometimes give the impression that there is an exponential skew. Maybe you can use the same methodologies for your data set? Look for Linear Mixed-Effects Models with Censored Responses.